# How to use filterstring in hb.scan.ex function from rhbase?

Tags: r, hbase

I wish to scan a table where my key is a timestamp and I want to add a filter to the timestamps. The doc pages don't say anything about how to give the filter. Should it be as we would do it in the hbase shell but as a string?

EDIT: I figured this out for "=" filters. Meaning, I am able to filter rows based on key = "something". But I need to use this for key > "something". I think this won't be possible as I went through the documentation of filters for hbase and it(Rowfilter) seems to be implemented only for equal to.

Answer (score 0):

If timestamp is your rowdy, then you can use startrow = yourstart_timestamp which should return all timestamp > yourstart_timestamp.